# Flex datagrid component problem

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, flex4, mxml

Guys I've a grid view in flex,

one of the columns is rendered like this:

```
<mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Cancel"  >
      <mx:itemRenderer>
       <fx:Component>
        <mx:Box width="100%" height="100%" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle">
         <mx:Button label="Download" width="100%"  >
          <mx:click>someFunction();</mx:click>
         </mx:Button>
        </mx:Box>
       </fx:Component>
      </mx:itemRenderer>
      </mx:DataGridColumn>
```

now I've a problem that the function in button click is not being recognized. It says "call to a possibly undefined function" even though it was defined. What is wrong with this? How do i make a button in a grid call a function in the same mxml file??

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `itemRenderer` is considered its own encapsulated component so it's looking for `someFunction()` within the `itemRenderer` itself. To call a function you have defined in the mxml file that contains your `DataGrid`, try calling the function using `outerDocument.someFunction();`.

If you would like to define the function at the itemRenderer level, you could do something like this:

```
<mx:itemRenderer>
  <fx:Component>
    <mx:VBox>
      <fx:Script>
      <![CDATA[

        public function someFunction():void
        {
          // Do Something
        }

      ]]>
      </fx:Script>

      <mx:Button click="someFunction();"/>
    </mx:VBox>
  </fx:Component>
</mx:itemRenderer>
```

Comment: Neat, very nice. you saved my day.

Comment: thank you so much for this!  Saved my day too.  Shaking my head at Adobe though...  What the heck!?  Why can't the IDE tell you this if it's a common mistake?